# Miss Relationship Using Cypher Query in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am working on Cypher query using **UNWIND** and **Foreach** in Neo4j. I am sure there is a bug, but I cannot figure out where I did wrong.

I am building a graph with three spans in a trace as follows (in "test.json")

```
   [
    {
        "spanId":"3",
        "name": "checkOut",
        "parentId": ["1"],
        "service_name": "svc"
    },
    {
        "spanId":"2",
        "name": "addCart",
        "parentId": ["1"],
        "service_name": "svc"
    },
    {
        "spanId":"1",
        "name": "frontend",
        "service_name": "svc"
    }
]
```

Span `checkOut` and `addCart` are child of `front`, so there are parent-child relationships between `frontend -> checkOut` and `frontend -> addCart`.

Meanwhile, these spans all belong to "svc" service, so they should have relationship to "svc". However, `frontend` misses the relation to "svc". See below

[image]

My Cypher query is as follows:

```
WITH 'file:///test.json' AS url

CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value

MERGE (s:Span {span_id: value.spanId})
ON CREATE SET  s.name=value.name, s.service=value.service_name

WITH s, value
UNWIND value.parentId AS parent
MERGE (p:Span {span_id: parent})
MERGE (p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s)

WITH s, value, value.service_name AS ki
FOREACH(k IN ki | 
     MERGE (svc:Service{service: value.service_name} )
     MERGE (s)-[:FROM_SERVICE]->(svc)
)
```

Can someone help me see where I did wrong in the Cypher query? A ton of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `UNWIND` statement, your `frontend` object doesn't have a `parentId` array, so there is nothing to unwind there and the object gets lost, before creating a relationship to service. To fix this, you should move the creation and merge of relationship with service above `UNWIND`. Try this:

```
WITH 'file:///test.json' AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value
MERGE (s:Span {span_id: value.spanId})
ON CREATE SET  s.name=value.name, s.service=value.service_name
WITH s, value, value.service_name AS ki
FOREACH(k IN ki | 
     MERGE (svc:Service{service: value.service_name} )
     MERGE (s)-[:FROM_SERVICE]->(svc)
)
UNWIND value.parentId AS parent
MERGE (p:Span {span_id: parent})
MERGE (p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s)
```